# Ruby Nokogiri. Match dynamic attribute names

Tags: ruby, xpath, nokogiri, dry

I'm trying to extract image url using Nokogiri.
The code below works, but I'd like to do in in a more efficient and scalable  way, not doing elsif infinitely.

```
if doc.at_css("img[itemprop='image']")['src']
    img = doc.at_css("img[itemprop='image']")['src']
elsif doc.at_css("img[itemprop='image']")['data-src']
    img = doc.at_css("img[itemprop='image']")['data-src']
elsif doc.at_css("img[itemprop='image']")['data-react-src']
    img = doc.at_css("img[itemprop='image']")['data-react-src']
...
```

I'd like to learn both approach:

1) Plain Ruby way: Like iterating attributes names like `['src', 'data-src', 'data-react-src', etc...]`

2) Nokogiri regex or xpath, approach:

```
'src' || 'data-src' || 'data-react-src
```

like this:

doc.at_css("img[itemprop='image']")['src' || 'data-src' || 'data-react-src]

Even better, store attribute names in a variable:

```
my_attributes = ['src' || 'data-src' || 'data-react-src]

doc.at_css("img[itemprop='image']").[my_attributes]
```

3) If there is a more efficient approach than previous ones

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
attributes = %w[src data-src data-react-src]
elem = doc.at_css("img[itemprop='image']")
attr = attributes.find { |attr| elem[attr] }
doc[attr] if attr
```

**What it does:**

1. Holds the list of static and dynamic attributes. Add more in future. Order of list is important [ref  #3]
2. `elem` holds the element(`Nokogiri::XML::Element`). We don't want to fetch it multiple times to optimize.
3. `attr` holds the first *attribute* which element *responds to*. If `src` is found, it won't try to find in `data-src` and so on. This way we optimized the iterations.
4. return the value at that `attr`ibute, if attribute is available.

Hope it helps.